# how to separate backend and frontend in docker nuxt

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nuxt.js, nodejs-server

I would separate nuxt app and dockerize backend and frontend path in a different folders.

fronted - one container (nuxt js)
backend - second container (express js)

project structure folders

```
  my_nuxt_app
   |-backend
   |-frontend
   docker-compose.yaml
```

when I create local that construction is work

```
  serverMiddleware: [
    {path: '/api', handler:'../backend'}
  ],
```

but how to create this on docker i don`t understand?

need link to container in **serverMiddleware** settings but i don`t undestand how please if yo know help me.

```
version: '3'
services:
  forntend:
    container_name: forntend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

backend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine

RUN npm i --location=global  --force pm2

RUN npm i --location=global  --force yarn

WORKDIR /backend

COPY . .

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "backend.js","--json","--no-auto-exit","--only","backend"]
```

frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine
 
RUN npm i --location=global  --force yarn

WORKDIR /mmc

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn","dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `serverMiddleware` property.
Just change this props in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
server:{
  host:'0.0.0.0,
  port:8080
},
```